# Uniform Convergence of Differentiable Functions

Tags: real-analysis

I was going over an old final exam when I came across the following problem.  I have a solution (provided by the professor), but it feels really unintuitive.  I have thought about this for some time, but my instincts seem to lead me to a dead end every time.  I'll describe my thoughts after I state the problem.  Here is how it appears on the exam:

"Let $f_n:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \, (n \geq 1)$ be differentiable and there exists an $M>0$ such that

$$|f'_n(x)| \leq M|f_n(x)|, \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall x \in [a,b], \, n \geq 1.$$

Moreover, $f_n(a) \to 0$.  Show that $f_n(\cdot)$ is uniformly convergent to $0$."

My instincts were to iteratively use the Mean Value Theorem.  For example, a natural first stab at the problem to me seemed to be something roughly like this:

$$\begin{align}
    |f_n(x)| &\leq |f_n(x)-f_n(a)|+|f_n(a)|\\ \\
             &= |f'_n(\xi)||x-a|+|f_n(a)|\\ \\
             &\leq M|f_n(\xi)||x-a| + |f_n(a)|\\
\end{align}$$

I then imagined one could continue this process on $|f_n(\xi)|$, but this is where I run into a dead end. I can't seem to see where the estimate will settle down, and where I can then pull uniform convergence out of it.  I've certainly tried many things here, but I get stuck every time.  Maybe there is a different direction one can take it from here, if this is still salvageable.

To give you an idea of what I mean by my professor's approach being unintuitive (at least to me) without writing it out in full, he observes that:

$$\begin{align}
   |f_n(x)|^2 &= |f_n(a)|^2 + \int_a^x2f_n(t)f'_n(t)dt\\ \\
              &\leq |f_n(a)|^2 + 2\int_a^x|f_n(t)||f'_n(t)|dt\\ \\
              &\leq |f_n(a)|^2 + 2M\int_a^x|f_n(t)|^2dt\\
\end{align}$$

and eventually he concludes that

$$|f_n(x)|\leq e^{M(x-a)}\leq e^{M(b-a)}|f_n(a)| \to 0$$

Of course, I am leaving many details out. This approach makes perfect sense, but I just never would have thought about the problem in this way, and wonder if there is any merit at all to my original line of reasoning.

I appreciate any feedback or advice you might have with regard to this problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Your professor's approach appears to be proving the Gronwall lemma.

Comment: @Ian It does seem to look a bit like that (I'd never heard of that until you just now mentioned it).

Comment: what does the n in  $f_n$ mean?

Comment: @user50224 It's just the index.  $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions, kind of like you may have seen $\{a_n\}$ as a sequence of, for example, real numbers.  An example of a sequence of functions might be $f_n(x)=x^n$, $x\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The first line should be

$$f_n^2(x)=f_n^2(a)+\int_a^x2f_n(t)f_n'(t)dt$$

which is easy to see since $\frac{df_n^2(x)}{dx}=2f_n(x)f_n'(x)$.  After that, one applies the triangle inequality to obtain

$$\left|f_n(x)\right|^2\le \left|f_n(a)\right|^2+\left|\int_a^x2f_n(t)f_n'(t)dt\right|$$

Comment: Oh, duh!  Thanks.  Any thoughts on alternate approaches?

Comment: Is that where you were stuck?

Comment: Well, yes.  But I was mostly curious if there was another way to do it.  Like I said, his proof makes sense (especially now after you cleared up the first line), but I wondered if there was a more "direct" route.  These sorts of tricks just never pop into my brain at the right time.  Can the Mean Value Theorem be used, for example?

Comment: Yea, I did that, but my concern is now that $M$ gets larger and larger exponents (granted, I'm multiplying by successively smaller interval lengths).  I just couldn't get it to work out much after that.  Also, I should have made it more clear: my professor just made the estimates above, then he cleverly defined a function $\theta(x)$ equal to the last estimate he made. He then estimated $\theta'(x)$, which is where the exponential function entered.  If you want, I can post his entire proof as an edit.  Just let me know.